Finding out all common columns in a set of tables
I have this table in SQL that contains a list of all tables and columns in these tables:
CREATE TABLE master_table (
    table_name VARCHAR(50),
    column_name VARCHAR(50)
);

INSERT INTO master_table (table_name, column_name) VALUES
('table1', 'col1'),
('table1', 'col2'),
('table1', 'col3'),
('table1', 'col4'),
('table2', 'col1'),
('table2', 'col3'),
('table2', 'col5'),
('table3', 'col1'),
('table3', 'col3'),
('table4', 'col1'),
('table5', 'col1');

I want to find out all common columns in these tables.  The final result should look like this:
 table_name col_name
    table_1     col1
    table_2     col1
    table_3     col1
    table_4     col1
    table_5     col1

I tried doing this with a CTE approach:
WITH common_columns AS (
    SELECT column_name
    FROM master_table
    GROUP BY column_name
    HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT table_name) = (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT table_name) FROM master_table)
)
SELECT m.table_name, m.column_name
FROM master_table m
JOIN common_columns c ON m.column_name = c.column_name
ORDER BY m.table_name, m.column_name;

But I am getting a NULL response
Can someone show me what I am doing wrong?

Your code actually looks fine.  Can you create a demo here: dbfiddle.uk ... then paste the link as a comment?

The issue is not reproducible, the query returns the expected result for your sample data. See this sample fiddle. It seems you have simplified your use case too much and lost the reason why it fails on your system?

If you want to find columns that are present in all tables then you could use basic aggregations and fiter the data with HAVING clause as you did in your cte:
--       S Q L 
Select   column_name
From     master_table
Group By column_name
Having   Count(table_name) = ( Select Count(Distinct table_name) 
                               From   master_table )

/*  R e s u l t :
COLUMN_NAME
-----------
col1

... to fetch the rows - use the above code as Where clause filter to test the result that should be the same as with your main SQL using JOIN (which also works fine - with sample data provided) ...
--      S Q L 
SELECT mt.table_name, mt.column_name
FROM   master_table mt
WHERE  mt.column_name IN( Select   column_name
                          From     master_table
                          Group By column_name
                          Having   Count(table_name) = ( Select Count(Distinct table_name) 
                                                         From   master_table )
                        );

/*     R e s u l t : 
TABLE_NAME  COLUMN_NAME
----------  -----------
table1      col1
table2      col1
table3      col1
table4      col1
table5      col1           /*

See the fiddle here.
